# How do banks balance the books after a borrower defaults on loan repayment?

Tags: loans, banking, accounting, balance-sheet

**Buyer** gets a 10k loan to buy a tractor from **Seller**.

In the banks' books:

###### Buyer

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 10k deposit | 10k repayment later |

###### Bank

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 10k repayment later | 10k deposit for Buyer |

###### Seller

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| - | - |

---

After the tractor is bought it looks like this:

###### Buyer

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| - | 10k repayment later |

###### Bank

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 10k repayment later | 10k deposit for Seller |

###### Seller

| Assets | Liabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 10k deposit | - |

Now what happens here when **Buyer** will be completely unable to repay, say, he dies? Will the "10k repayment later" asset remain on the banks' balance sheet forever? If it is removed, what replaces it in order for the balance sheet to remain balanced?

I suppose the banks' equity position reduced?

Comment: Perhaps this question can be simplified by forgetting tractors and sellers and just focusing on how [bad debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_debt) is accounted? As in, what do I do if I lend you 10k and you disappear with the cash?

Comment: The balances in your example are incomplete At the start the seller has a tractor.  It also serves as collateral while the loan exists. Also there is no guarantee that the seller will keep their funds in that particular bank.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep True. Let's just assume Buyer and all his collateralized assets disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the specifics of the scenario (transfer to estate, recovery of collateral), here's how basic Bad Debt is accounted for:

Bad Debt is an expense for the lender. It's a decrease in an asset account and an increase in an expense account.

For the borrower, it would be an income ("Forgiven Debt?") since they had a reduction of debt and no change in assets.

Both would get wiped out after the books are closed and revenue/expense accounts are moved to equity ("Retained Earnings")

Also note that your accounting of "after the tractor is bought" is wrong, but that's not your question.  It may help you figure it out if you include income accounts as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the buyer dies his estate will inherit the debt (if they want to receive the inheritance they will have to pay the debt). This is not an absolute safety, as maybe no one wants to accept the inheritance (debts are higher than assets) or there may be other situation (bankruptcy).

In your specific case in which the loan is to be used buying a defined item, the lender may place a *lien* on the item(s), in this case the tractor, making it a secured loan. If the borrower defaults, the lender may try to recover the item(s), and sell them to pay back the outstanding debt. The lender has priority against other debtors.

This is neither 100% safe: the item may be not enough to cover the debt, or it may not even be available (it was stolen or destroyed in a fire). And not all loans are secured.

Typically, when the bank detects some loan that has a high risk of not getting returned, it will make a provision for the value it estimates may be lacking. That provision is an asset that comes at the expense of less money being available to loan. This help ensure that the bank does not borrow over its own possibilities; it won't count that it will have the tractor money back to loan it again.

That money is accounted as a loss for the bank. This is in line with the general rule of accounting that losses must be reported when it becomes apparent that they will happen, not when they are finally realized.

When it is finally settled the amount that will not be recovered, then that amount is deducted from the provision; any remaining money from the provision goes back to the bank as profit.

Comment: His "state" or his "estate"?

Comment: Do you know what the position in the balance sheet is then called?